# Como dar un valor por defecto a un array de string en MongoDB? (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy creando un esquema MongoDB con un array de URL para fotos.
El problema que tengo es que no consigo dejar una por defecto para el caso de que el usuario no suba ninguna foto.

```js
photos: {
  type: [String],
  default: ['https://res.cloudinary.com/dkejgwlha/image/upload/v1592555603/friends_amcn0b.png']
}
```

He probado de esta forma pero cuando hago una instancia, lo miro en la BBDD y no me da ningun valor por defecto.

Comment: Deberías detallar más la pregunta. Por favor, revisa [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cuando creas una instancia o cuando salvas un documento?

Comment: Cuando creo un anuncio en la App que estoy haciendo. No se si me explico bien @MauricioContreras

Comment: Pues acabo de probar tu código y funciona de maravillas, ¿Qué versión de Mongoose estás usando? Yo uso la versión `5.9.19`. ¿Podrías hacer un `console.log()` después que creas la instancia justo antes de salvar el documento a base de datos? Imagino que usas: `const data = new Model();`. ¿Podrías añadir más código? El problema no es la forma en que declaras el campo, al parecer es como creas la *instancia* del modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Un valor por defecto en el array cada vez que se crea un elemnto por el equema:

```
let arrayFotosSchema = new Schema({
    unArray: {
      type: Array,
      'default': ['https://res.cloudinary.com/dkejgwlha/image/upload/v1592555603/friends_amcn0b.png']
    }
});
```

Comment: El código del OP también funciona (al menos en Mongoose 5.9.19), el problema parece ser otro. Saludos

Comment: Seria recomendable añadir mas código para ver donde surge el problema, de paso todos aprendemos un poco mas.

Comment: Exacto, por eso le dejé mi comentario al OP. Por cierto, no es necesario poner el nombre del atributo `'default'` entre comillas. Es un objeto de Javascript, y a menos que el nombre use caracteres no permitidos para nombres de variables, podemos omitir las comillas. Saludos

Comment: eso es Correcto!

Comment: Hola a todos. Mañana hago un edit con más código y os etiqueto a todos. Creo que @Mauricio Contreras va bien encaminado y el problema viene al crear la instancia.

Answer (score 0):

Pongo la solución.

```js
photos: {
  type: Array,
  default: 'URL'
},

// En el momento de crear la instancia, lo pude solucionar con esta linea.
// Añadir que estaba utilizando un middleware y parecía que al estar 
// vacío pasaba algún dato.
req.file ? req.file.path : photos = undefined;
```

Si alguien tiene alguna duda, que me diga y lo miramos.